# User informix holding onto table lock

Tags: sql, informix, aix

I am running Informix v12.10 on AIX. 
The problem I am having occurs when logged in as user informix. I will run a simple query in SQL such as "select colour from oceans;"

This will obviously place a open cursor lock on that table — great.  Now to find if the lock is actually on the table, I use:

```
onstat -g opn > filename.txt
```

redirecting the output to a file so we can sift through it.  Then

```
cat filename.txt | grep -p hexnumber
```

where the `hexnumber` is the hexadecimal number of the table. I then get the user with

```
onstat -u | grep session id
```

Now, the lock is held by user informix, and when I close the session and wait any amount of time and redo the processing, the lock remains.

Please advise on why this lock is not freed.

Comment: What does the `-p` do on the `grep`?  With BSD `grep`, it indicates "do not follow symlinks in a recursive search"; with Linux, it seems to have no meaning (Ubuntu 16.04).  And is there any reason not to use `grep -p hexnumber filename.txt`?  (The last is mostly rhetorical — I'm basically sure there isn't a good reason not to make `grep` open the file.)  None of this directly affects your underlying problem, though.

Comment: You say 'the hexadecimal number of the table'.  How did you establish that number?  (`SELECT HEX(partnum) FROM 'informix'.systables WHERE tabname = 'ocean';`?).  Why are you using `onstat -g opn` rather than `onstat -k` to determine which locks are held?  How are you establishing the session ID?

Comment: Roughly, please can you join the dots a bit more explicitly.  Can you show the header lines for the section of the `onstat -g opn` information?  I'm tempted to ask "why are you working as user informix", but we can skip over that.  More significantly, does this only happen with user informix, or would you see the same effect with another, less privileged user?  When you run the query on table `oceans`, are you using DB-Access?  Has DB-Access stopped running when you're checking later — or what does "close the session" mean?

Comment: As mentioned by Jonathan there's not too much to work with here at the moment. What type of locks are being shown? Perhaps the full onstat -g opn or onstat -k output would help. 
In general a select statement shouldn't place anything more restrictive than share locks on a table or rows unless the database is mode Ansi or the session isolation is greater than last committed. And these locks only remain whilst the select statement is active. Also, the locks may belong to the informix user for a different session, such as the dbscheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the backend Informix session is terminated the reference to the table will be gone.

What do you mean by "close the session"?

If you just close the application and the application does not close the connection then the session can be active for a while

1. The server session may still be processing sql - if so the server will not notice the client application has gone until the sql completes and the server received an error that it cannot send results to the client application.
2. If the server session is not processing sql the server will be waiting for a command from the client.  Until something like TCP/IP keepalive kicks in the server session will be stuck inside a network read call and the session will not go away.

Once the server receives an error that the client is gone the server will still have to rollback any active transactions (which could take hours with GB's of active transaction!).

Once transaction rollback is complete the server will cleanup/free active cursors/prepared sql statements after that the server session will go away.

You can use `onstat -g ses` and `onstat -g stk` on the session threads to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

A table being opened is not a lock. With the obvious "self promotion" warning, I would suggest you should use "ixtableuse" (https://github.com/domusonline/InformixScripts/blob/master/scripts/ix/ixtableuse). It should give you information if there is anything preventing an ALTER table for example.

If you find it useless, please tell me why. If you find it useful but you find any issue, please do the same.